# Why does GCC take so much longer to build than llvm/clang?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, llvm

This is a question about the process of building the compilers themselves. On my machine, compiling gcc (for C, C++, and objc) takes **hours**, while llvm + clang + clang++ is probably 10-20 minutes, depending.

Why such a big difference?

Comment: Try compiling only c/objc/c++ support (no java), without bootstrap - otherwise gcc builds itself 3 times, while clang/llvm is normally built only once and you have to bootstrap it manually.

Comment: Ah, it's the bootstrap. Thanks.

Comment: @SK-logic This should be the answer.